# Can RDS snapshots be transferred across AWS accounts?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In the time since [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/220180/184431) was answered, AWS Tools for Powershell has been released and I basically have the same problem: I have an RDS snapshot on one AWS account that I would like to transfer to another.

So far I've been able to select the snapshot that I want with the `Get-RDSDBSnapshot` cmdlet, and I'd like to take that `Amazon.RDS.Model.DBSnapshot` object and use it in the other account.

I've been looking around and I think the `Restore-RDSDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot` cmdlet (maps to [rds-restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot.html)) might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not confident that I understand its behavior -- can this cmdlet be used to take my snapshot from my first account, and restore it to an instance in the second account?

I'm specifically concerned if there are any account-specific details in a Snapshot object or the handling of the cmdlet that would prevent that data from moving across accounts. I would be okay with a more general solution than powershell, if one exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2015/10/29:**

AWS has added native support for this functionality since my original posting ([link to announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-update-cross-account-snapshot-sharing/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20AmazonWebServicesBlog%20%28Amazon%20Web%20Services%20Blog%29)). This is supported for unencrypted MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL.

You are given the option to share your RDS snapshot publicly, or privately (by managing specific AWS Account IDs with permission to view your snapshot).  By default, snapshots can be privately shared with up to 20 accounts.

This can be managed from the RDS console by clicking 'Snapshots (left navigation bar) > Share Snapshot (top toolbar)', which leads you to the following UI:

[image]

This is also available in the RDS API and CLI.

---

**Original Answer:**

I also posted this to the AWS Developer Forums, and got a [response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=478000) from PhilP@AWS. It seems like we can't do this at all, via powershell or any other means.  He did have a couple of alternate suggestions, though:

> It's not possible to directly share an RDS Snapshot from one account
>   to another. However I can make a couple of suggestions here (depending
>   on your current configuration):
>
> If your RDS Instance is publicly accessible:
>
> - Launch a new RDS DB onto your second account
> - Install the appropriate DB management tools onto a PC, and give this PC network access to both RDS instances (security groups and DB user access for read and write)
> - Using the database management tools to copy the data from one DB to the other DB
>
> Copy data through an EC2 instance as an intermediary:
>
> - Launch an EC2 instance configured with appropriate DB server software
> - Copy the RDS DB Data from your RDS instance up to your EC2 instance
> - Then launch your new RDS instance into the second account
> - Configure appropriate access (security groups and DB user access for read and write)
> - Copy the database data from your EC2 instance to your newly created RDS instance

My RDS instance isn't publicly accessible, and of his suggestions the EC2 solution would be preferable.  We could alternate back to using a mysqldump, per the Server Fault solution.

**Edit:** I wanted to update that I've successfully been able to implement the EC2 intermediary suggestion. This can be automated several ways, but the solution I chose involved passing a bash script to the (linux AMI) EC2 instance as user-data, and the details of data transfer were handled in the script.

This solution ended up being fairly cost-effective, with the caveat that you want the RDS instance and the EC2 instance to be in the same availability zone.  This is in large part because [data transfer between RDS-EC2 in the same availability zone is free](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#DataTransfer) with a private IP address.

Comment: What if I have multiple databases on single RDS instance?
Do I have to perform these steps for each database separately?

Comment: With the sharing method, how do we access those shared snapshots from the other account?

Comment: You can use api - ```aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot SNAPSHOT_ID``` Note: If you are restoring from a shared manual DB snapshot, the SNAPSHOT_ID must be the ARN of the shared DB snapshot. You can get it with ```aws rds describe-db-snapshots```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon finally made it possible to accomplish this. You can share the snapshot with another account using the Edit-RDSDBSnapshotAttribute cmdlet ([example here](http://www.dataasapet.com/2016/03/12/how-to-share-an-rds-snapshot-with-aws-tools-for-windows-powershell/)), then you can restore it to an account the snapshot was shared with using the Restore-RDSDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot cmdlet.

You can even share encrypted snapshots now. Here's [a good walkthrough](http://www.dataasapet.com/2016/03/09/how-to-share-an-encrypted-rds-snapshot-with-another-aws-account/) on how to do that.