# Backing up aws RDS oracle database to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oracle11g

I have my oracle database running on amazon web services(aws) in RDS instance. 
The total size of the database would be less than 100gb. I am planning to take the backup of entire database, particularly I want to backup the database to S3. 
Can any one suggest me a solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

For backups within AWS you can use the snapshot function of RDS. Snapshots can be used to restore your database to a point in time.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html

However, you can not download these snapshots or access them physically.

If you want backups on S3 you have to dump the databases and upload the dumps to S3

See

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

[Download MySql Backup/Snapshot from Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401741/download-mysql-backup-snapshot-from-amazon-rds)

Comment: Native backups / restores to an S3 bucket are supported for SQL Server on AWS but not yet for Oracle RDS. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-support-for-native-backuprestore-to-amazon-s3/